# Determining the type of a value based on a if check on another value

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, error-handling, strong-typing

I want my code editor to infer the type of `extraData` based on the value of `error` which is being narrowed by the if statement:

```ts
export enum ErrorCodes {
  Unknown = 'UNKWN',
  BadRequest = 'BDREQ',
}

interface ExtraData {
  [ErrorCodes.Unknown]: string,
  [ErrorCodes.BadRequest]: number,
}

let error: ErrorCodes;
let extraData: ExtraData[typeof error];

if(error === ErrorCodes.Unknown){
  console.log(extraData) // on hover VS code says it's a string | number  
}
```

But if I put the `extraData` type assigment *inside* the if block then it works:

```ts
export enum ErrorCodes {
  Unknown = 'UNKWN',
  BadRequest = 'BDREQ',
}

interface ExtraData {
  [ErrorCodes.Unknown]: string,
  [ErrorCodes.BadRequest]: number,
}

let error: ErrorCodes;

if(error === ErrorCodes.Unknown){
  let extraData: ExtraData[typeof error];
  extraData // on hover VS code says it's a string  
}
```

I don't want to do that in every conditional block since there will be dozens of error codes and I can't validate using `typeof` since we will use objects as the actual extra data

Comment: Well in the general case `error` and `extraData` could be completely unrelated, TS won't let you do this. In general type refinement on a value does not refine the type of other things

Comment: @AndreaSimoneCosta isn't there any way to achieve a similar result?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wgAG0m) meet your needs?  The only way this could work is if `error` and `extraData` are both fields of a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) where `error` is the discriminant.  If the above works for you then I can write up an answer explaining; if not, please [edit] your example code to show how it fails.  Let me know (pls mention @jcalz if you reply so I'm notified).

Comment: Yes @Jenryk, you should pack your data together

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgazgewO5ygXigbwFBSFQDGyAJhAFxQDkMAcgNIDq9NBREAHsAE4CGAEX7B+1AM58AlnADmeAL548oSFABC-MgCUIARwCuESVlwdCpCtRrrB2gKIBFdkSjc+QkWKhwDAWwAjCF5FZVVoe15eZF5xU3gkNAwAHw0tXUNjYGUKYgAbfl5oPIhgNyiY6kjo2IBuZSkAMwAKYJqAOktoTB7aBhY2AEp8QjaY9vcBYVEOAHpZ1ygAPQB+RSA

Comment: @jcalz It does, thank you. I'll wait for the explanation.

Comment: Where do `extraData` and `error` actually come from? In your toy example, they are uninitialised global variables, what are they in your real code? Are they part of a generic function perhaps?

Comment: @Bergi They will come from args in an error-handling function, which will be responsible for parsing the codes (and extra data) and returning a human-readable message

Comment: Is the function called right where the error occurs, or is it used to post-process an error value that was passed around? Most likely the discriminated union type, as suggested by jcalz, is the way to go.

Comment: But if he starts with unrelated `error` and `extraData` in the first place, he won't be able to build an instance of the suggested `ErrorAndExtra` without a cast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `error` and `extraData` are just two variables of the type `ErrorCodes` and `ExtraData[typeof error]` respectively, there's nothing you can do.  `ErrorCodes` is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), and so `ExtraData[typeof error]` is also a union type.  Two union types are always treated as independent or uncorrelated with each other.  The type `typeof error` is just `ErrorCodes` and doesn't "remember" anything about `error`.  There is no way to say in types that two separately-declared variables are of *correlated union types*.

So if you'd like `error` to be something you can check and have the check have an effect on the apparent type of `extraData`, you can't declare them separately.  Instead they should be declared together as fields of a single [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) type.  Here's one way to express such a type:

```
type ErrorAndExtra = { [K in keyof ExtraData]:
  { error: K, extraData: ExtraData[K] }
}[keyof ExtraData]

/* type ErrorAndExtra = {
    error: ErrorCodes.Unknown;
    extraData: string;
} | {
    error: ErrorCodes.BadRequest;
    extraData: number;
} */
```

The `ErrorAndExtra` type is a union where each member has a discriminant `error` property of [literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) type, and an `extraData` property whose type depends on the type of the `error` property.

If you had a variable of type `ErrorAndExtra`, you could get the narrowing behavior you're looking for:

```
declare const e: ErrorAndExtra;
if (e.error === ErrorCodes.Unknown) {
  console.log(e.extraData.toUpperCase()) // okay
} else {
  console.log(e.extraData.toFixed()) // okay
}
```

That might be sufficient for you; still, you can get the same behavior with two separate variables, as long as you [destructure them](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-6.html#control-flow-analysis-for-destructured-discriminated-unions) from a value of the discriminated union type:

```
declare const { error, extraData }: ErrorAndExtra;
if (error === ErrorCodes.Unknown) {
  console.log(extraData.toUpperCase()) // okay
} else {
  console.log(extraData.toFixed()) // okay
}
```

This also works; TypeScript understands that `error` and `extraData` came from the `ErrorAndExtra` discriminated union, and so the check on `error` has the effect on `extraData` you're expecting.

Again, this only works because the declaration of `error` and `extraData` is specifically following a pattern that TypeScript supports for this purpose.  If you change the pattern, it could break.  For example:

```
declare let { error, extraData }: ErrorAndExtra;
if (error === ErrorCodes.Unknown) {
  console.log(extraData.toUpperCase()) // error
} else {
  console.log(extraData.toFixed()) // error
}
```

Here we changed the declaration from a `const` to a `let`.  And that breaks the spell.  Since `let` variables can be reassigned, the compiler would have to track such assignments before it could verify that a check on `error` should have any effect on the apparent type of `extraData`, and it's not considered worth the extra work for the compiler to do this.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.4#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwKJStAwhAE2AGc4BvAWACg44BVRAa0QgHdE4BeOAcjoDkA0gHV+PADTVaAIQCGBAErAAjshLxuPaQBEFGAIoTqAX2rUAlohjAoAM1kBjYJhAwos7bJizyUuAG0sHCh8ImIAOgZmNkQAXQAuOGI3SwBzSRoAoLxCEnC5RRU1ZIS4FFQAIxsM0ypqGABPMGdsqABBRAIMV3cucgDBOEs4RmAGiFsXNw8vWQS-MgRsaETBcQQeme9E7unPb39BWLha439R8cnd93256gB6ACo4RubMZfbO659uSkzaGzBHYfUJ5KIsdgAbj8AM2t0SySgaWhVGMcAAPr5-ksge9gqCIgUlKp1CjaLC9rNEuUqlAUWjHvczFQiA4ADayKDOBwQRDJBDA4IdLqbFEWSYACmA4UB0C4nG4rQJkSYEMQAEosbQeXyIGzpWyIKkpTK4bNwjAIHQwM0QrJiMAJerNfd7nAIIxZA0TAg2Q6tXAdcQ9QajSbQJTvBaIAAxcwgYAEJ0ut0er0mZmsjlcwO8-mLWVQdYRm6zE6C6DC74o8ySwvyxUg3IRcExTV-bV5kPhQ3GktbWTR6223D2x3OuCu92e72o33+ju53X6nth-u3aNxhNJidTtOz2rURCyVAkMCOZwAeQgYFIi6znOc+vgBY+xbN3nLeMrX1FflrcBSh8DbfiEzYqtE7DtjCS7BiuvZSh+g6WsONijg6yaTm6hZ+GiwB+s4i6dsuoZ9khm7xommFTjhmSnEAA)